# Does there exist a contractible fiber bundle with fiber $G(\infty)$ and base $SU(\infty)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

[Bott periodicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity) implies that $\Omega(SU)\simeq G(\infty)$. Here, by $G(\infty)$, I mean the direct limit $\underset{m\to \infty}{\lim} G_m(\mathbb{C}^{2m})$ where $G_m(\mathbb{C}^{2m})\subset G_{m+1}(\mathbb{C}^{2m+2})$ by stabilization (or some similar nice model for $BU$). This is the classifying space for $U = \underset{m\to\infty}{\lim} U(m)$, and may be identified with $U/(U\times U)$, where the coordinates of each factor of the product subgroup alternate. From the path space construction, one knows that there is a contractible Serre fibration $\Omega SU \to E \to SU$, where $E$ is the space of paths in $SU$ from the identity. The fibers are each homotopic to $G(\infty)$.

The question I have is whether this may be realized by a contractible fiber bundle $G(\infty)\to E \to SU$ ? Other quasi-fibrations were given by Aguilar and Prieto, and by [Behrens](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1886093). There are also fibrations of this sort constructed using symplectic reduction by [Latour](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1088270) and by [Giroux](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8592391/msri10.pdf), where the fibers are homotopic to $G(\infty)$. What I'm asking for is whether  there  exists a contractible fiber bundle rather than just a fibration or quasi-fibration?

Presumably such a bundle would arise from a map $SU \to BDiff(G(\infty))$. The isometry group of $G(\infty)$ contains $SU$, so one could ask *a fortiori* whether there is a map $SU \to BSU$, that is a map $f: SU \to G(\infty)$, such that the induced fiber bundle is contractible? **Added clarification:** The induced bundle would come from the fiber product of the pull-back of the $U$ bundle $U\to E \to G(\infty)$ with the action of $U$ on $G(\infty)$: $f^{*}(E) \times_{U} G(\infty)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that I understand your notation, so this may be not what you want, but in case it is close enough, I'll have a go.  The bit I'm assuming is that $G_m$ is the Grassmannian of $m$-places in $\mathbb{C}^{2m}$.  That seems fairly safe, but my brain is refusing to check the homotopy types of everything involved at this hour.

I think that you can do this if you combine a construction of mine from [The Co-Riemannian Structure of Smooth Loop Spaces](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Research/Preprints/coriemloop.html) with some bits from *Loop Groups* by Pressley and Segal, and then check a few details about how stuff holds together in the limit.

The bit that you need from *Loop Groups* is that the polynomial loop group, $\Omega_{\text{pol}} S U(n)$ acts on the *finite* restricted Grassmannian $Gr_0(H)$.  Let me remind you what that space is: we start with the *polarised Hilbert space*, $H = L^2(S^1,\mathbb{C}^n)$, polarised as $H = H_+ \oplus H_-$ where $H_+$ are those functions with only positive Fourier coefficients and $H_-$ with strictly negative Fourier coefficients.  From this, we define

$$
Gr_0(H) = \{W \subseteq H : \exists k : z^k H_+ \subseteq W \subseteq z^{-k} H_+\}
$$

This **is** the union of $Gr(H_{-k,k})$ where $H_{-k,k} = z^{-k}H_+/z^kH_+$ so this (if I'm reading things aright) is the $G(\infty)$ of your question (*Loop Groups*, section 7.2).

The next bit that we need is that $\Omega_{\text{pol}} SU(n)$ acts on this space.  This is from Theorem 8.3.2 and Proposition 8.3.3 in *Loop Groups*.

Putting these two together, if we have a principal $\Omega_{\text{pol}} SU(n)$-bundle over a space then we get a $G(\infty)$-fibre bundle over said space.

So now comes the bit from my work.  In Section 3.2.3 of *The co-Riemannian Structure of Smooth Loop Spaces*, I construct a principal $\Omega_{\text{pol}} SU(n)$-bundle over $SU(n)$, with the property that under the obvious inclusion $\Omega_{\text{pol}} SU(n) \to \Omega SU(n)$ then this becomes the bundle coming from the usual path construction (so, although I don't need this in that paper, Bott periodicity implies that it is contractible).

So now we have a fibre bundle with fibre $G(\infty)$ over $SU(n)$.  The last bit that you need is to show that under the inclusion $SU(n) \to SU(n+1)$ then these fibre bundles are compatible.  The bit where this needs care is in the action of $\Omega_{\text{pol}} SU(n)$ on $Gr_0(H)$.  But I think that if you include $L^2(S^1, \mathbb{C}^n)$ in to $L^2(S^1, \mathbb{C}^{n+1})$ at the same time, then you should get a diagram that works.  The resulting Grassmannian will be $\bigcup Gr_0(L^2(S^1,\mathbb{C}^n))$ but that will still be $G(\infty)$ (assuming that I've understood the question correctly).

As I said, there's a few ifs and buts here: *if* I understood the question correctly, and *if* everything holds together in the limit (but I'm pretty sure that the second "if" is fine), but obviously as I'm less sure about the first if I haven't checked all the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that sounds promising. I'll have to do some reading on Loop groups to understand your answer. 

Answer (score 1):

This is a lousy answer, but it gets you part of the way.  There is an $E_\infty$ H-space structure on $G(\infty)$ given by direct sum of subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^\infty$.  Consequently one is entitled to form the classifying space $B(G(\infty))$.

Now, one can rectify $G(\infty)$ into a group; that is, there is a group $G$ and a homotopy equivalence $G \to G(\infty)$.  For instance, one could take $G$ to be the Kan loop group on the singular complex of $B(G(\infty))$, a (very large) group model for $\Omega B(G(\infty)) \simeq G(\infty)$.  Then one gets a homotopy equivalence $BG \simeq BG(\infty)$.

Bott periodicity implies that there is a homotopy equivalence $SU \to B(G(\infty))$.  Replace this with a map $f: SU \to BG$.  The associated principal $G$-bundle $E \to SU$ is contractible, since $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.  So you get a contractible fiber bundle over $SU$ with fibre homotopy equivalent to $G(\infty)$.

That's not quite what you want.  If you could show that the homotopy equivalence $G \to G(\infty)$ was via an action that mimicked left translation in $G$, then you can form the simultaneous quotient $E \times_G G(\infty)$; this would be precisely the sort of object that you had in mind.

I'm also ignoring the issue about whether the universal bundle $EG \to BG$ is in fact a fibre bundle; $G$ is potentially sufficiently exotic that the standard theorems about Lie groups don't necessarily hold.  Again, though, if you could show that $G$ acts on $G(\infty)$ nicely, then you could realize $G$ (as you say above) as a subgroup of $Diff(G(\infty))$, where I believe that the result is known to hold.